# How to set default value in grails g:select?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

I have domain object City

```
City{
Long id
String city
...
 String toString() {
        return "$city"
 }
}
```

Say table is like this.

```
id  name 
1   ABC
2   PQR
3   XYZ
```

list of cities I populate in gsp like this

```
<g:select name="city" from="${City.list()}"  />
```

Now I need to populate default value of city which comes from controller something like this

```
cmd.city = "PQR"
render template:'messageDisplay', model:[cmd: cmd]
```

Now I am trying to populate default value "PQR" in select list

```
<g:select name="city" from="${City.list()}" value="${cmd.city}" />
```

but "PQR" doesn't show up as default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Strings and City objects and are trying to compare them...

Change your select to:

```
<g:select name="city"
          from="${City.list()}"
          value="${cmd?.city?.id}"
          optionKey="id" />
```

And in your controller:

```
cmd.city = City.findByName( "PQR" )
```

Comment: oh! can it be done other way round? like can I get the list of strings with city names instead of city objects?

Comment: You could try: `from="${City.list().name}"`